# AngularJS sorting by property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do is sort some data by property. Here is example that I tought should work but it doesn't.

HTML part:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in testData | orderBy:'value.order'">
            {{value.order}}. {{key}} -> {{value.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS part:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.testData = {
        C: {name:"CData", order: 1},
        B: {name:"BData", order: 2},
        A: {name:"AData", order: 3},
    }

}]);
```

And the result:

> 3. A -> AData
> 4. B -> BData
> 5. C -> CData

... that IMHO should look like this:

> 1. C -> CData
> 2. B -> BData
> 3. A -> AData

Did I miss something (here is ready [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZEnK/14/) to experiment on)?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

AngularJS' orderBy filter does just support arrays - no objects. So you have to write an own small filter, which does the sorting for you.

Or change the format of data you handle with (if you have influence on that). An array containing objects is sortable by native orderBy filter.

Here is my **orderObjectBy** filter for AngularJS:

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
 return function(input, attribute) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    var array = [];
    for(var objectKey in input) {
        array.push(input[objectKey]);
    }

    array.sort(function(a, b){
        a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
        b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
        return a - b;
    });
    return array;
 }
});
```

Usage in your view:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:'position'">
    //...
</div>
```

The object needs in this example a position attribute, but you have the flexibility to use any attribute in objects (containing an integer), just by definition in view.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "123": {"name": "Test B", "position": "2"},
    "456": {"name": "Test A", "position": "1"}
}
```

Here is a fiddle which shows you the usage:
http://jsfiddle.net/4tkj8/1/

Comment: This is great. I added the option to sort asc/desc: app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
 return function(input, attribute, direction) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    var array = [];
    for(var objectKey in input) {
        array.push(input[objectKey]);
    }

    array.sort(function(a, b){
        a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
        b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
        return direction == 'asc' ? a - b : b - a;
    });
    return array;
 }
});

In HTML: <tr ng-repeat="val in list | orderObjectBy:'prop':'asc'">

Comment: @Armin what if this is object like array? i.e. `{1:'Example 1', 2:'Example 2', 3:'Example 3', ...}`

Comment: You could just keep the "attribute" parameter empty and remove first two lines in sort function. But this example directive just sorts numbers, not text. `{1:'2', 2:'1'}`would work than.

Comment: Great answer BUT we lost the key of the object this way. To keep it, just add it creating new array's rows in the filter e.g. `for(var objectKey in input) { input[objectKey]['_key'] = objectKey; array.push(input[objectKey]); }` Like that we can use `<div ng-repeat="value in object | orderObjectBy:'order'" ng-init="key = value['_key']">`

Comment: It's worth noting that Angular.js **does** support sorting by a property in an array of objects now: `... | orderBy: 'name'`.

Comment: @Wildhoney This question is about ordering objects with keys, not arrays containing objects.

Comment: Hello all can you plz tell me how i can do the same with angular 2 or 4

Answer (score 30):

It's pretty easy, just do it like this

```
$scope.props = [{order:"1"},{order:"5"},{order:"2"}]

ng-repeat="prop in props | orderBy:'order'"
```

Comment: This does not work for associative arrays, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget that parseInt() only works for Integer values. To sort string values you need to swap this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
  a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
  b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
  return a - b;
});
```

with this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
  var alc = a[attribute].toLowerCase(),
      blc = b[attribute].toLowerCase();
  return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the code of angular-JS ( https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js ) ng-repeat does not work with objects. Here is a hack with sortFunction.

http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/qaK56/33/

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="test in testData | orderBy:sortMe()">
            Order = {{test.value.order}} -> Key={{test.key}} Name=:{{test.value.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>

myApp.controller('controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var testData = {
        a:{name:"CData", order: 2},
        b:{name:"AData", order: 3},
        c:{name:"BData", order: 1}
    };
    $scope.testData = _.map(testData, function(vValue, vKey) {
        return { key:vKey, value:vValue };
    }) ;
    $scope.sortMe = function() {
        return function(object) {
            return object.value.order;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

according to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy , orderBy sorts an array.
In your case you're passing an object, so You'll have to implement Your own sorting function.

or pass an array -

```
$scope.testData = {
    C: {name:"CData", order: 1},
    B: {name:"BData", order: 2},
    A: {name:"AData", order: 3},
}
```

take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qaK56/

Comment: I know that it works with arrays.. So the solution is to write my own sorting function?

Comment: Your jsfiddle != your code u posted. This is the right jsfiddle for your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qaK56/92/

Answer (score 3):

You should really improve your JSON structure to fix your problem:

```
$scope.testData = [
   {name:"CData", order: 1},
   {name:"BData", order: 2},
   {name:"AData", order: 3},
]
```

Then you could do

```
<li ng-repeat="test in testData | orderBy:order">...</li>
```

The problem, I think, is that the (key, value) variables are not available to the orderBy filter, and you should not be storing data in your keys anyways

Comment: tell that to Firebase ;)

Comment: as far as i know, you create the data in firebase

Comment: If you store an array in Firebase, it uses a UID as the key for the array.  There are many situations where one doesn't get control over the data structure, so your suggestion might be a bit sweeping.

Comment: store an array of what? One always has control over data structure. Also the OP mentions nothing about Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i did and it works.
I just used a stringified object.

```
$scope.thread = [ 
  {
    mostRecent:{text:'hello world',timeStamp:12345678 } 
    allMessages:[]
  }
  {MoreThreads...}
  {etc....}
]
```

`<div ng-repeat="message in thread | orderBy : '-mostRecent.timeStamp'" >`

if i wanted to sort by text i would do

```
orderBy : 'mostRecent.text'
```

Answer (score 2):

I will add my upgraded version of filter which able to supports next syntax:

```
ng-repeat="(id, item) in $ctrl.modelData | orderObjectBy:'itemProperty.someOrder':'asc'
```

---

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){

         function byString(o, s) {
            s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
            s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
            var a = s.split('.');
            for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
                var k = a[i];
                if (k in o) {
                    o = o[k];
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            return o;
        }

        return function(input, attribute, direction) {
            if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

            var array = [];
            for(var objectKey in input) {
                if (input.hasOwnProperty(objectKey)) {
                    array.push(input[objectKey]);
                }
            }

            array.sort(function(a, b){
                a = parseInt(byString(a, attribute));
                b = parseInt(byString(b, attribute));
                return direction == 'asc' ? a - b : b - a;
            });
            return array;
        }
    })
```

Thanks to Armin and Jason for their answers in this thread, and Alnitak in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key).

Answer (score 1):

Armin's answer + a strict check for object types and non-angular keys such as `$resolve`

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
 return function(input, attribute) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    var array = [];
    for(var objectKey in input) {
      if (typeof(input[objectKey])  === "object" && objectKey.charAt(0) !== "$")
        array.push(input[objectKey]);
    }

    array.sort(function(a, b){
        a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
        b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
        return a - b;
    });

    return array;
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The following allows for the ordering of objects **by key** OR **by a key within an object**.

In template you can do something like:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(k,i) in objectList | orderObjectsBy: 'someKey'">
```

Or even:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(k,i) in objectList | orderObjectsBy: 'someObj.someKey'">
```

The filter:

```
app.filter('orderObjectsBy', function(){
 return function(input, attribute) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    // Filter out angular objects.
    var array = [];
    for(var objectKey in input) {
      if (typeof(input[objectKey])  === "object" && objectKey.charAt(0) !== "$")
        array.push(input[objectKey]);
    }

    var attributeChain = attribute.split(".");

    array.sort(function(a, b){

      for (var i=0; i < attributeChain.length; i++) {
        a = (typeof(a) === "object") && a.hasOwnProperty( attributeChain[i]) ? a[attributeChain[i]] : 0;
        b = (typeof(b) === "object") && b.hasOwnProperty( attributeChain[i]) ? b[attributeChain[i]] : 0;
      }

      return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    });

    return array;
 }
})
```

Comment: is it normal that the keys of (k,i) in objectList are transformed into 0's and 1's?