# How do you sort an AngularFire collection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

```
  $scope.items = [];
  var ref = new Firebase("https://****.firebaseio.com/");
  var query = ref.limit(5);

  angularFire(query, $scope, "items");
```

---

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" >
<span>{{item.title}}</span>
</div>
```

How would you sort these by "title"?  I've seen a couple similar questions but the solutions don't seem to work, at least for this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$scope.items` were an array of objects (as implied by `$scope.items = []`), you would be able to use the angular `orderBy` [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy):

```
<!-- This example will NOT work with Firebase -->
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'title'">
  <span>{{item.title}}</span>
</div>
```

**However**, setting `items` to an array as you did is misleading, because you are actually storing (and retrieving) your "items" as a list of key value pairs, **not** an array. Sorting objects in javascript is more complicated in general, but one way to achieve what you want is a custom filter:

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
  return function(input, attribute) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    var array = [];
    for(var objectKey in input) {
      array.push(input[objectKey]);
    }

    function compare(a,b) {
      if (a[attribute] < b[attribute])
        return -1;
      if (a[attribute] > b[attribute])
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    array.sort(compare);
    return array;
  }
});
```

Now you can use your filter to order by any of your `item` properties:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:'title'">
  <span>{{item.title}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/Bnvnn/3/) to demonstrate. As @bennlich noted below, your custom filter could stop at the array conversion and then you could use the normal orderBy filter, as suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286#issuecomment-14303275).

And just to be thorough I should note that you could also sort "server-side" with Firebase [priorities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html).

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to do anything, I don't even get an error when I give it a nonsense value.

Comment: Are you storing `items` as an array in firebase?

Comment: Yep, using the Firebase PHP library: https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

    $story = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'id' => $id
);




$response = $fb->set($storyPath, $story);

Comment: I'm not familiar with the php library but my guess is you aren't actually storing your `stories` as an array of story objects with "sortable" attributes. If you could post a screenshot or some representation of the data from your forge it would be easier to tell. If you can't sort it with a normal angular filter you'll have to [write your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property) or sort it with firebase [priorities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html).

Comment: Ah, I don't think I know how to give them sortable attributes and I don't think Firebase PHP can do setpriority, here's a shot: http://imgur.com/QZ7tkpQ EDIT: better shot: http://imgur.com/q4DcRvX

Comment: Ok so yeah that isn't an array, you'll probably want to make your own filter or restructure the data. Also, since you are using angularfire, you might not need the php library at all.

Comment: There's also [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286#issuecomment-14303275) method: a filter that converts to an array, followed by the normal orderBy filter.

Comment: @Spider since you can store arrays I'm not sure it is accurate to say that the first example "will not work with Firebase." It just depends on the object type you are retrieving.