# Angular JS - How to filter a list using multiple links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem using the filter function in Angular JS.
I have to filter my list using different links.
I can't understand how to filter the list. Tried some examples but it doesn't work. How can I do it??
This is my code now:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="rubric in examplerevisions | filter:myFilter" class="{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].class}}">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].createdBy}}</td>
    <td>{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].createdOn | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].action}}</td>
    <td>{{rubric.action}}</td>
</tr>

<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = {action: 1}">OK</a>
<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = {action: 2}">New Proposal</a>
<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = {action: 3}">Null</a>
```

**JS**

$scope.examplerevisions contains all my rows

**JSON EXAMPLE ARRAY**

```
{
"1":{
    "id":1,
    "action":1,
    "translationProposal":{
        "id":1,
        "status":"ACCEPTED",
        "createdOn":1393946608751,
        "createdBy":12,
        "validations":[
            {
                "id":0,
                "action":"ACCEPT",
                "proposedAlternative":"Traduzione alternativa",
                "createdOn":1393946608751,
                "createdBy":12
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="rubric in examplerevisions | filter:myFilter" class="{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].class}}">
<td></td>
<td>{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].createdBy}}</td>
    <td>{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].createdOn | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{rubric.translationProposal.validations[0].action}}</td>
    <td>{{rubric.action}}</td>
</tr>

<a href="" ng-click="myFilter[1].action = 1}">OK</a>
<a href="" ng-click="myFilter[1].action = 2}">New Proposal</a>
<a href="" ng-click="myFilter[1].action = 3}">Null</a>
```

that should do a trick, if you want to filter object by values of it nodes then myFilter needs to be a root for your object

------edit----------

dunno why I haven't noticed it straight away, filter doesn't really work with object of objects, you need an array of objects, check updated version of your plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ejbZXqhwdrF1yopIaM61?p=preview

Comment: Yes thanks! It works now! I did it 1hr ago and it works. Thanks

Comment: My answer was actually first, but is basically the same :P

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the last example of the page: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter, I think the parameter should be something like `ng-click="myFilter.action = 1"` or `myFilter[1].action = 1`

Could you provide a JsFiddle or something where one could try?

**EDIT:** I don't know if it's possible to do it like that. I would probably write my own filter for that. Or I would convert the JSON into an array, like I did here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/S9MvwFlpczWxqciVP72V

or look at this answer if you want to stay with the object format:
[AngularJS sorting by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property)