# Sorting javascript objects in array by properties (angularjs filter)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort an array of javascript objects by their properties for an angularjs application. I need to be able to sort by Numbers and Strings.

So far i have expanded the filter from Armin provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property) to sort numbers and strings (see code below).

What i am still missing is the ability to give a nested property (like `user.surname`) to the filter. It should be dynamic, so that i would be able to provide any depth of nested properties to it. Is there a way to do this?

Here's my filter code:

```
angular.module('app')
    .filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
        return function(input, filterBy) {
            if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

            var attribute = filterBy;
            var reverse = false;

            if (filterBy.substr(0,1) == '-') {
                attribute = filterBy.substr(1);
                reverse = true;
            }

            var array = [];
            for(var objectKey in input) {
                array.push(input[objectKey]);
            }

            if (parseInt(array[0][attribute])) {
                array.sort(function(a, b){
                    a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
                    b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
                    return a - b;
                });
            } else {
                array.sort(function (a,b) {
                    if (a[attribute] < b[attribute]) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (a[attribute] > b[attribute]) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
            }

            if (reverse) {
                return array.reverse();
            } else {
                return array;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: see using filters effects the performance and if you are sorting on 100+ i.e. (nos of rows* nos of columns) data elements then i don't think you should approach it using filters. Rather write a directive which would re position objects in your scope object which you use in ng-repeat

Comment: From the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy There is an example of usage of the `orderBy` filter on an array of objects, and the filtering is done on a property. How's that different from your problem ? The thread you mention is talking about sorting properties of an object ... not an array of objects.

Comment: @RishulMatta: I see your point... I don't think that the lists in my app will exceed 100+ items, at least none except one list. So i think i will use the backend to sort the list for me because it is an inhouse app, so bandwith and speed are not the problem. Nevertheless your idea using a directive sounds good, i will test this as well.

Comment: @TimothéeJeannin: ah yes... i had an object of objects first but then changed it myself to an array. So now it is an array of objects. Haven't thought about the it again... organisation blindness i think... So but still there is the problem with the nested properties. How to iterate about a dynamic depth of nested properties to sort the objects inside the array after them?

Answer (score 1):

its pretty straight forward  check this out: http://jsbin.com/duzurazo/2/edit

you can use something like

```
  <li ng-repeat="prop in props | orderBy:'order.v'"> {{prop.order.v}} </li>
```

where model is something like

```
  $scope.props = [{order:{v:"1"}},{order:{v:"5"}},{order:{v:"2"}}];
```