# Sorting by property of JSON objects in AngularJS with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble sorting JSON objects based on their properties. I referred to this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186947/3496380 and it's comparing the actual property's value in its sort function yet the objects are still not sorted on the page (although they ARE in a different order, just not alphabetical)

Here's the relevant code:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">xxxxxxx</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>xxxxxx</h1>
    <p class="lead">xxx</p>


  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid thumbnail">

    <div class="col-xs-2" ng-repeat="champ in champions | orderObjectBy:'name'">

        <div class="">
      <h6>{{ champ.name }}</h6>
            <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/{{ versionNumber }}/img/champion/{{ champ.image.full }}" />


        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

The app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $sce) {

        // champion names json
        $scope.urlChampions = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion?champData=blurb,image&api_key=KEY";


        // grab list of champion names
        $http.get($scope.urlChampions).then(function(response) {
            $scope.champions = response.data.data;
            $scope.versionNumber = response.data.version;
        });

        $scope.trust = $sce.trustAsHtml;
    });

    app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
     return function(input, attribute) {
        if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

        var array = [];
        for(var objectKey in input) {
            array.push(input[objectKey]);
        }

        array.sort(function(a, b){
            //console.log(typeof a);
            a = a[attribute];
            b = b[attribute];
            //console.log(typeof a);
            //console.log(a + "  fsdfa  " + b);
            //console.log(a < b);
            return a < b;
        });
        return array;
     }
    });
```

Here's a link to the JSON array that's being grabbed: http://pastebin.com/V7Jb3xpn

EDIT: Got it to work by changing the array.sort function in app.js to the following

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    a = a[attribute];
    b = b[attribute];
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `array.sort` should return 1 (`a < b`), -1 (`a > b`) or 0 (`a === b`)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! (just had to switch < and > from your suggestion since it was sorted in reverse)