# Unknown provider: inputProvider when using $filter

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-filters

I've taken the orderByObject Filter from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property) post. But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: inputProvider <- input <- orderObjectByFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/$injector/unpr?p0=inputProvider%20%3C-%20input%20%3C-%20orderObjectByFilter
minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4031:19
getService@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4178:39
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4036:28
getService@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4178:39
invoke@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4210:1
enforcedReturnValue@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4072:20
invoke@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4219:14
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4037:20
getService@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4178:39
$FilterProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16724:14
FundController/</<@http://localhost:3000/app/fund/fund.controller.js:24:28
processQueue@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13300:27
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13316:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14555:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14371:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14660:13
done@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9734:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9924:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9865:1
angular.js (line 11707)
```

Here is how I've defined the filter:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .filter('orderObjectBy', orderObjectBy);


    function orderObjectBy(input, attribute) {
        console.info("orderObjectBy filter");
        if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

        var array = [];
        for(var objectKey in input) {
            array.push(input[objectKey]);
        }

        array.sort(function(a, b){
            a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
            b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
            return a - b;
        });
        return array;
    };
  })();
```

I'm using this filter my controller like so :

```
vm.getClasses().then(function(data){
    $filter('orderObjectBy')(data.data,'displayOrderEN' ));

});
```

where `data.data` is data from $http rest call and `displayOrderEN` is a property. Heres a sample of Json data:

```
[
  {
    "fundClassCode": "qqq",
    "displayOrderEN": 18,
    "displayOrderFR": 18
  },
  {
    "fundClassCode": "Aaaa",
    "displayOrderEN": 1,
    "displayOrderFR": 1
  },
  {
    "fundClassCode": "sss",
    "displayOrderEN": 2,
    "displayOrderFR": 2
  },
  {
    "fundClassCode": "dddd",
    "displayOrderEN": 12,
    "displayOrderFR": 12
  }
]
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EaIJIriq6SG7YPeG7K0g?p=preview

Comment: can you please make plunker of your attempt.

Comment: @mudasserajaz Here it is : http://plnkr.co/edit/EaIJIriq6SG7YPeG7K0g?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sWI2n0bMiqk42bA1V6BO?p=preview)

You need the function to return a function that angular can use. [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider)

The outer function is used so that you can inject services into your filter.

```
function orderObjectBy() {
    return function (input, attribute) {
        console.info("orderObjectBy filter");
        if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

        var array = [];
        for(var objectKey in input) {
            array.push(input[objectKey]);
        }

        array.sort(function(a, b){
            a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
            b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
            return a - b;
        });
        return array;
    }
}
```

There is also a typo:

```
vm.getClasses().then(function(data){
    $filter('orderObjectBy')(data.data,'displayOrderEN' )); //<--- extra parenthesis

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You were missing the invoking function - when creating a custom filter, the second argument is a parameterless function. Source - https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Change to:

```
.filter('orderObjectBy', function () {
      return orderObjectBy;
 });
```

Or alternatively just include that function in your `orderObjectBy` already.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jvEDbumUnxsGd9k7su8G?p=preview)