# Reverse the ng-repeat order in object with numeric keys

Tags: angularjs, object, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object which keys are years:

```
years: {
  "2100": {
    countingAgent: false,
    turns: 3,
    cards: 4,
    score: 3
  },
  "2000": {
    countingAgent: false,
    turns: 4,
    cards: 3,
    score: 4
  },
  "1900": {
    countingAgent: false,
    turns: 5,
    cards: 2,
    score: 6
  } ... 
}
```

I want the higher years to be first, I have this `ng-repeat`:

```
<li class="year" ng-repeat="(year, data) in years">
```

I tried `| orderBy:'year':true"` and `| orderBy:'score':true"` but none worked, it always puts 1900 first.

---UPDATE---

It seems all solution resolve around creating a filter converting object to array. Is there no solution that is more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

orderBy requires array, not object. You'd better simply convert your data.
Or implement simple filter:

```
app.filter('keyarray', function() {
  return function(object) {
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
      result.push(key);
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

In html:

```
<div ng-repeat="key in test | keyarray | orderBy : '-toString()'">{{key}} : {{test[key]}}</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BHm4dv2np4ysUAlJFaO3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-years`:

```
<li class="year" ng-repeat="(year, data) in years | orderBy:'-years'">
```

Data is sorted by `years` in descending order.

In your question, you put "orderBy:'year':true" but should be "orderBy:'year**s**':true"

--------EDIT---------

You should create a filter to order your object:

```
myApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function () {
    return function (input, attribute) {
        if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

        var array = [];
        for (var objectKey in input) {
            array.push(input[objectKey]);
            input[objectKey].year = objectKey;
        }

        array.sort(function (a, b) {
            a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
            b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
            return b - a;
        });
        console.log(array)
        return array;
    }
});
```

And then use this filter to order your repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in years | orderObjectBy:'position'">
    {{data.year}}
    {{data.countingAgent}}
    {{data.turns}}
    {{data.cards}}
    {{data.score}}
</li>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/z4v96s4v/1/

*My answer is based on this one : [AngularJS sorting by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property) with some changes for your situation.

Comment: Seems not. this is the actual code, maybe the object notation is problematic `<li ng-repeat="(epoch, turnpoint) in stats.stream | orderBy:'-stats.stream'">`

Comment: @ilyo Updated my answer

Comment: @Magicprog.fr it keeps the order as it was.

Comment: @ilyo Yes, sorry about that, updated once again. I've changed the order or years in fiddle, and it looks fine now :)