# AngularJS: Sort by date in ng-repeat where key is date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat, lodash

I'm using LoDash to create statistics out of some records in a IndexedDB.

```
$scope.refreshStats = function() {

    var dataByMonth = _.groupBy($scope.stats, function(record) { 
        return moment(record.date).format('MMMM YYYY'); 
    });

    dataByMonth = _.mapValues(dataByMonth, function(month) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.Cars = _.groupBy(month, 'car');
        obj.Drivers = _.groupBy(month, 'driver');

        _.each(obj, function(groupsValue, groupKey) {
            obj[groupKey] = _.mapValues(groupsValue, function(groupValue) {
                return _.reduce(groupValue, function(sum, trip) {
                    sum['trips']++;
                    sum['duration']+= moment.utc(trip.duration, 'HH:mm:ss');
                    sum['total'] = moment.utc(sum.duration). format('HH:mm:ss')
                    return sum;
                }, {trips: 0, duration: 0, total:0})
            });
        })
        return obj;
    });
    $scope.statistics = dataByMonth;
    console.log($scope.statistics);
};
```

The result from my function is a collection of nested objects which key is always a month and a year:

```
Object {
    July 2016: Object, 
    August 2016: Object, 
    September 2016: Object, 
    October 2016: Object
}
```

The problem is that when I display it in the frontend, the first ng-repeat grouped by months `monthName` will get ordered alphabetically (displaying August-July-September-October), and so far I didn't figure out how to order it by date.

Here's how the ng-repeat looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="(monthName, monthValue) in statistics">

    {{monthName}}

</div>
```

Is there any way to use `orderBy:date` when the date is they key of the object?

**EDIT**

The question is not repeated as my problem is the need to identify the Key as Date and then order by it. I haven't been able to solve this problem with the answers to the referred question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key order for object in JS can not be relied on, you'll have to convert your data in to a {date: , value: } object and sort it.

First step, conversion:

```
var step1 = _.map(_.pairs(dataByMonth), _.partial(_.zipObject, ['date', 'value'] ));
```

next you need to sort them:

```
var step2 = _.sortBy(step1, function(value){
  return new Date(value.date);
});
```

step2 holds your sorted value

```
$scope.statistics = step2;
```

you can use it in your ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="montStats in statistics">

    {{monthStats.date}}

</div>
```

You can further optimize your code by:

Keeping the date as a real date and avoid the parsing by each sort iteration.

Chain the operations:

```
_(dataByMonth).pairs().map(
  _.partial(_.zipObject, ['date', 'value'])).sortBy(function(value){
    return new Date(value);
  }).value();
```