# AngularJS, order text selection with a non-array model?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the `ng-options="ref as display for (ref, display) in` syntax to display a non-array object as a dropdown, but am having trouble ordering the dropdown values.

How should I use the `orderBy` filter to sort this dropdown by `display` value?

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <select name="category" type="text" ng-model="categories " ng-options="ref as display 
for (ref, display) in categories | orderBy:'display'" >

    </div>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.categories = {
          cat2: "Category 2",
          default: "anone",
          zone: "zone",
        };
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13412/

Comment: orderBy doesn't work for objects. You could convert your categories object to an array or you can implement a custom filter like this person: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186947/2506481](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186947/2506481). This is a possible duplicate of that question

Comment: @ero thanks. when I add a custom filter, as in the answer you linked the drop-down displays as desired, but it seems the `model` is now tied to the newly created array. When I select an item, the `model` value is `0`,`1`,or`2` as opposed to `cat2`,`default`, or `zone`. Any suggestions as to how I can customize the drop-down ordering without changing the bound `model`?

Comment: @ero, nevermind, I see this is addressed in that answer's comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Orderby** can't be applied to a plain object, alternatively you can define a method in the controller to convert the object to an array

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.categories = {
      cat2: "Category 2",
   default: "anone",
   zone: "zone",
 };
  
   $scope.templatesAry = function() {
      var ary = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(val, key)
      {       
        ary.push({
          "category": val          
        });
      });
      return ary;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.category as selection.category for selection in templatesAry()  | orderBy:'category'"></select>
</div>
```